# Subtract Blending Mode

Tags: photoshop, gimp, blending, color-blending, gegl

I have been trying to implement some of the layer blending modes of GIMP (GEGL) to Python. Currently, I am stuck in Subtract Blending mode. As per [documentation](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-concepts-layer-modes.html), `Subtract = max(Background - Foreground, 0)`. However, doing a simple test in GIMP, with `Background image = (205,36,50)` and `Foreground image = (125,38,85)`, the resultant composite image/colour comes to be `(170, 234, 0)` which doesn't quite follow the math above.

As per understanding, Subtract does not use Alpha Blending. So, could this be a compositing issue? Or Subtract follows different math? More details and background can be find in a separate [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69445671/gimp-poc-results-not-matching-with-gimp-for-subtract-blending-mode) question.

**EDIT [14/10/2021]**:
I tried with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVbOe.png) image as my Source. Performed following steps on images normalised in range `[0, 1]`:

1. Applied a Colour Dodge (no prior conversion from `sRGB -> linear RGB` was done) and obtained [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dorG3.png) from my implementation which matches with GIMP result.
2. `sRGB -> linear RGB` conversion on Colour Dodge and Source image. [[Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#The_sRGB_transfer_function_(%22gamma%22))]
3. Apply Subtract blending with `Background = Colour Dodge` and `Foreground = Source Image`
4. Reconvert `linear RGB-> sRGB`

I obtain [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGqha.png) from POC. Left RGB triplet: (69,60,34); Right RGB triplet: **(3,0,192)**. And the GIMP [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTMz2.png). Left RGB triplet: (69,60,35); Right RGB triplet: **(4,255,255)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking at channel values in the `0 ➞ 255` range they are likely gamma-corrected. The operation is possibly done like this:

- convert each layer to "linear light" in the `0.0 ➞ 1.0` range using something like

```
L = ((V/255) ** gamma) (*)
```

- apply the "difference" formula
- convert the result back to gamma-corrected:

```
V = (255 * (Diff ** (1/gamma)))
```

With `gamma=2.2` you obtain 170 for the Red channel, but I don't see why you get 234 on the Green channel.

(*) The actual formula has a special case for the very low values IIRC.

Comment: Thanks. This definitely what seems to be happening internally in GIMP. As for the value `G = 234`, I must have made a mistake. Tried to reproduce this in tool, but could not. However, I am still facing issue when combined with other blend option. My original post is updated with this information. Can you give some hint here?